# React Native Expo Horizontal and Vertical Scrolling - Android and iOS

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-ios

I have implemented horizontal scrolling with the following code: https://snack.expo.io/H1CnjIeDb

How to implement multiple rows of horizontal red-blue boxes (keeping horizontal scrolls), with rows that can be scrolled vertically.

Additionally, how do I programtically add `<View style={styles.view} />` inside scroll view, for both horizontal and vertical scrolling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve **multiple rows of horizontal red-blue boxes (keeping horizontal scrolls), with rows that can be scrolled vertically** by **Nested scroll view**

you can achieve **programmatically add  inside scroll view, for both horizontal and vertical scrolling** by using Map function. Check [Expo snack](https://snack.expo.io/@sivakumar00/2dec3a). I have implemented what you need.

```
 <ScrollView
        ref={scrollView => {
          this.scrollView = scrollView;
        }}
        style={styles.container}
        //pagingEnabled={true}
        horizontal={false}
        decelerationRate={0}
        snapToInterval={width - 60}
        snapToAlignment={'center'}
        contentInset={{
          top: 0,
          left: 30,
          bottom: 0,
          right: 30,
        }}>
        {array.map(item => {
          return (
            <ScrollView horizontal={true}>
              {array.map(item => {
                return (
                  <View style={item % 2 === 0 ? styles.view : styles.view2} />
                );
              })}
            </ScrollView>
          );
        })}
      </ScrollView>
```

If answer satisfies you, Upvote it :-)